# Speed up nested loops

Tags: python, performance, loops

Im doing a challenge concerning triangular numbers. The point is to find out if the sum of any two of the triangular numbers equals the input n. I got it to work, but apparently it takes too long and they would like something faster.

The way I wrote it, it puts all the triangular numbers into a list, then I loop through the list to check if any pair of numbers meet the conditions. I have no idea how to make the loops faster, and reading through similar posts on here I dont know how to apply it to this situation.

Here is the code:

```
def Triangular(n):
    lst = []
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        lst.append((i** 2 + i)//2)
    yn = False
    for i in lst:
        for j in lst:
            if i*i + j*j == n:
                yn =  True
                break
            else:
                continue
    return yn
```

Comment: You might want to ask on [codereview.se]

Comment: _"The point is to find out if the **sum** of any two of the triangular numbers equals the input n"_ - then why does your code look at the **sum of the squares**?

Comment: Because I mistyped

Comment: So I tried Triangular(6), which should return True, but instead received false. Slightly confused here >.>

Comment: Nvm, just realized that's a typo

Comment: Actually that is a problem, reading over things it says it need to be two squared consecutive triangular numbers add up to n. This may be why it passes all the test cases but not the final case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the *squares* of the triangular numbers in a d̶i̶c̶t̶i̶o̶n̶a̶r̶y set (not a list).  Then go through the d̶i̶c̶t̶i̶o̶n̶a̶r̶y set and for each key, ask if the key is less than or equal to `n/2` and if `n - key` is also a key in the l̶i̶s̶t set.

It would be `O(n log n)` worst case, instead of `O(n^2)`, and noticeably faster.

And of course, `break` only breaks out of one level of the loop, so you can succeed much faster by returning true.

Comment: That would be it, even just returning true did it. I dont know what I was thinking, thank you for the help.

Comment: I don't understand how a statement `if i <= (n/2) and (n-i) in lst` satisfies the condition if placed in dictionary? A user case is n = 2, where the result should technically be False.

Comment: What's wrong with a `set`? BTW `in` is O(1) for dict and set so should this just be O(n)?

Comment: @AChampion -- a set would be better. I stopped using Python before set() was added to the language.  Fixed now.